# How does this piece of code function as fast i/o?

Tags: c++, io

I am unable to comprehend how this function results in faster i/o in c++.
please help me out!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define FOR(A,B,C) for(int A=B;A<C;A++)
#define EFOR(A,B,C) for(int A=B;A<=C;A++)
#define RFOR(A,B,C) for(int A=B;A>=C;A--)

using namespace std;

inline void Input(int &N)
{
int ch;
N=0;

while((ch<'0'||ch>'9')&&ch!='-'&&ch!=EOF)
    ch=getchar();

do
    N=(N<<3)+(N<<1)+(ch-'0');
while( (ch=getchar())>='0' && ch<='9');

return;
}

int main()
{
unsigned int fn[100005],gn[100005];
fn[0]=1,gn[0]=1,fn[1]=1,gn[1]=0;
int MOD=100000;

EFOR(fill,2,100001){
    fn[fill]=(fn[fill-1]+fn[fill-2]+2*gn[fill-1])%MOD;
    gn[fill]=(fn[fill-2]+gn[fill-1])%MOD;
}

int T;
Input(T);
while(T--){
    int N;
    Input(N);
    printf("%u\n",fn[N]%10000);
}

return 0;
}
```

This code without that inline function is getting TLE but with it, it's getting AC
If i am using just cin or scanf to take input i am getting a TLE

Comment: faster than what?

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. `ch` is never established with a value prior to its initial comparisons in that while-conditional.

Comment: What is TLE and AC? (I think I know, but I shouldn't have to ask). What *game* are you playing with this software? Some online programming challenge website?

Comment: This code is a buggy mix of poor programming style and pointless attempts at optimization. It is not "fast i/o".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming first line is: `int ch = getchar();`

```
while((ch<'0'||ch>'9')&&ch!='-'&&ch!=EOF)
    ch=getchar();
```

These lines skip all the characters that are not number. Although you should use `-` properly.

`(N<<3)+(N<<1)` is equivalent to `N * 8 + N * 2` or `N * 10`.

`(ch-'0')` will convert the character `ch` from printable character to number.

Adding to previous result `10 * N` will append newly read character to N.

It may be faster than formatted input using `cin` or `printf("%d", &N)` for the following reasons:

- Raw input is read instead of formatted.
- Multiplication using shifting

Comment: Thanks for answering!!.Can you please explain to me what do you mean by you should use '-'  properly??

Comment: Multiplication by a compile-time constant replaced by shift-and-addition is more likely to slow down the code than to speed it up. Modern platforms offer much better options for multiplication by compile-time `10` than shift-and-addition. The only hope in this case is that the compiler is smart enough to reverse-engineer these shifts back into multiplication by `10` and then reimplement it properly.

Comment: @AnT These are some methods used by people in competitive programming after a lot of profilation. Needless to say OP has messed up with the code. Although I rarely use it, these tricks were sometimes helpful when input/output was intense in test cases. In production code for customer, such cost is almost never nevessary.

Comment: Tricks like this can be useful under some very specific circumstances. Multiplication by compile-time 10 is not one of them. Whoever uses it in "competitive programming" is either confused or does it as part of their signature style. There is no rational reason to do it.

Comment: @AnT Can't agree any less with you. Mostly with -O2, there is no need to write ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

The code skips all non-digit characters, then reads all digits and accumulates them into a number.

```
N=(N<<3)+(N<<1)+(ch-'0');
```

is an optimization of

```
N = N*10+(ch-'0')
```

that is totally unecessary on most compilers / platforms.

Bugs and portability issues:

- ch is not initialized
- entering '-' ends input with N=0. this is probably not intended

Comment: Even in EBCDIC 0-9 are contiguous. Moreover C specs guarantee these to be contiguous. a-z may or may not be contiguous.

Comment: Thanks @MohitJain. removed it.